# Apply CSS to Html.Action()

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, html-helper

I am working with ASP.net MVC3, how I can add a CSS class to an `@Html.Action()`. I have done the following, but it isn't working:

```
@Html.Action("ProductEmailAFriendButton", "Catalog", new { productId = Model.Id, @class="test" })
```

Comment: `@Html.Action` renders a child action not a hyperlink. You need to use `@Html.ActionLink` to generate a hyperlink

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
@Html.ActionLink("ProductEmailAFriendButton", "Catalog", new { productId = Model.Id},new{@class="test",@id="someid", @style="background:none #fff";})
```

provide the class in the 4th argument i.e. htmlattributes, hope you will get the idea

Answer (score 2):

Are you sure you don't want an ActionLink? Action() can't have any Html attributes applied to it since it renders your action and returns a string representation of it. Also, you are mixing route values and HTML attributes in your code. I think below is what you are looking for. It will render a link to an action:

```
@Html.ActionLink("ProductEmailAFriendButton", "Catalog", new { productId = Model.Id }, new { @class="test" })
```

If Html.Action is what you intended (i.e. you want to physically render the action to a string) and you want to apply a CSS class to the parent container of the rendered view then you could do something similar to below:

```
<div class="test">@Html.Action("ProductEmailAFriendButton", "Catalog", new { productId = Model.Id })</div>
```

Comment: Thanks Ryan. You are right ! Html.Action() can't have CSS applied to it ! Here's what it was giving me:

http://i52.tinypic.com/11w3eh2.jpg

Html.Action was getting a PartialView. I needed to get to the Partial View and change things there.

Thanks so much for the help. :)